# replacing characters in a string to help mysql import

Tags: bash, sed, awk, cut, tr

I have the below

`fname sname    2   4   06:30   5   125%    32  27  84%`

I would like to change it to this

`'fname sname', '2', '4', '06:30', '5', '125',  '32', '27', '84'`

Any ideas on how to do this in a single command?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
echo 'fname sname 2 4 06:30 5 125% 32 27 84%' | \
sed 's/%//g' | \
sed -E "s/(^[a-z0-9:]+ [a-z0-9:]+|[a-z0-9:]+)/'\1',/g" | \
sed 's/,$//'
```

Here is the explanation of the sed commands:

1. Strip the % signs from the string.
2. Wrap the words with single quotes with a comma at the end

   - The first two words are wrapped with their own set of quotes.
   - To make this case insensitive, replace all occurrences of `[a-z0-9:]` with `[a-zA-Z0-9:]`
3. Remove the last comma from the string.

Comment: For making `sed` replacements case-insensitive you should use the modifier `i`: `s/foo/bar/gi`

Comment: came out like this (all on new lines)
F'name'
S'name'
'2'
'4'
'06:30'
'5'
'125'
'32'
'27'
'84'

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The i modifier only works with certain versions of sed.

Comment: @ubuntu101010101 Thats odd. What shell are you using? My command works with bash 3.2.48 and sed version 7.

Comment: They were all seperated by tabs so i added this in - maybe it brke it?`| tr "\t" " " | your code here ` I'm using bash 4.1.5 and sed 4.2.1

Comment: If you add the exact output of the command then we can figure out whats going on. If everything was on newlines then you may need to use tr to replace those as well. I also see that your output has an upper case F and S. That would require a slight change to the regex to make it case insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

For instance like this:

```
... | sed -r "s/%//g; s/ ([0-9])/', '\1/g; s/^|$/'/g"
```

This `sed` command does 3 replacements:

- `s/%//g`: remove all `%` characters
- `s/ ([0-9])/', '\1/g`: replace all spaces followed by a digit with `', '` and the digit
- `s/^|$/'/g`: put single quotes at beginning and end of the string

Comment: Yup, just noticed and fixed.

Comment: I didn't know you could do multiple sed commands like that. Great work.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
$ echo "fname sname 2 4 06:30 5 125% 32 27 84%" | 
  awk '{ 
  sub(/[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+/,"\x27&\x27");
  gsub(/[0-9:]+/,", \x27&\x27"); 
  gsub(/%/,"")}1'
```

**Output**:

```
'fname sname' , '2' , '4' , '06:30' , '5' , '125' , '32' , '27' , '84'
```